# Sleep inside Future in Scala.js

Tags: future, scala.js

Is it possible to sleep inside a Future in Scala.js ?

Something like:

```
Future {
   Thread.sleep(1000)
   println("ready")
}
```

If I try this then I get an exception saying that `sleep` method does not exist.

It seems like that it is possible to sleep in JS : [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) even though it is not possible to block.

Comment: Just use `pausecomp` from the linked solution :) (I assume you are fully aware of why you would not want to do this most of the time).

Comment: I think the answer given below is perfectly fine and there is no reason why someone should not use that anytime they wish to delay a future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot really pause in the middle of the future body, but you can register your future as a followup to a "delay" Future, which you can define as:

```scala
def delay(milliseconds: Int): Future[Unit] = {
  val p = Promise[Unit]()
  js.timers.setTimeout(milliseconds) {
    p.success(())
  }
  p.future
}
```

and which you can then use as:

```scala
val readyLater = for {
  delayed <- delay(1000)
} yield {
  println("ready")
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether you actually want to sleep a specific amount of time or just want something to happen "later" (which is often needed for testing), note the notYet function in the jsExt library, which does a looser version of this: https://github.com/jducoeur/jsext

Comment: Hm... I don't really get what you mean ... later ? who decides what is later ? later in respect to what ? do you have an example ?

Comment: @JustinduCoeur Any correct `Future` is `notYet` according to what the readme describes. The API doc on `ExecutionContext` says: "A general purpose ExecutionContext must be asynchronous in executing any Runnable that is passed into its execute-method.". (we have been doing this wrong in SJS with the `runNow` `ExecutionContext`). So the example  you give with the `watcher` is IMO a bit bogus since given a correct `ExecutionContext` `watcher.fullyReady` will not be called before `setup` returns (in JS, on the JVM there is an inherent race, with or without `notYet`).

Comment: Huh -- useful to know.  `notYet` certainly made a difference when I created it, but that was admittedly a long time ago, and may have been needed against `runNow`...